# Deserialize JSON without field name

Tags: c#, json.net

I have below JSON.  When I am deserializing it, `responseHeader` and `response` work fine but `highlighting` does not.

Issue is  highlighting data is like as shown below , `_text_` comes null. I want to store both the values in two fields. Problem is first part does not have any constant field name.

```
1. C:\\TestArea..........
2. _text_

  "highlighting":{ 
        "C:\\TestArea\\Destination\\SUP000011\\ATM-1B4L2KQ0ZE0-0001\\SoS_Update_2018_06_04_pram.pptx":{
          "_text_":["\nSCRUM of SCRUMs S4-W1 \n AXP Internal \n 4-<em>Jun</em>-18 \n \n slide-master-content   \n \n  \n slide-notes   \n 4-<em>Jun</em>"]},
```

JSON:

```
{
    "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 115,
        "params": {
            "q": "\"John\"",
            "hl": "on",
            "hl.simple.post": "</em>",
            "start": "0",
            "rows": "10000",
            "hl.simple.pre": "<em>"
        }
    },
    "response": {
        "numFound": 10,
        "start": 0,
        "docs": [{
            "domain": ["FIU/FCRU"],
            "id": "C:\\TestArea\\Destination\\SUP000011\\ATM-1B4L2KQ0ZE0-0001\\SoS_Update_2018_06_04_pram.pptx"

        }]
    },
    "highlighting": {
        "C:\\TestArea\\Destination\\SUP000011\\ATM-1B4L2KQ0ZE0-0001\\SoS_Update_2018_06_04_pram.pptx": {
            "_text_": ["\nSCRUM of SCRUMs S4-W1 \n AXP Internal \n 4-<em>Jun</em>-18 \n \n slide-master-content   \n \n  \n slide-notes   \n 4-<em>Jun</em>"]
        },
        "C:\\TestArea\\Destination\\SUP000005\\F-3-20150505-0028\\tt.csv": {
            "_text_": [",NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL\r\n930,<em>John</em> Ferguson,NULL,2015-06-30 15:27:04.677,test.test"]

        }
    }
}
```

My data model and code:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public ResponseHeader responseHeader { get; set; }
    public Response response { get; set; }
    public Highlighting highlighting { get; set; }
} 
public class Highlighting
{   
    public List<string> _text_ { get; set; }
}

var outObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString, new JsonSerializerSettings() { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `highlighting` property use a `Dictionary<string, Highlighting>` like so:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public ResponseHeader responseHeader { get; set; }
    public Response response { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Highlighting> highlighting { get; set; }
} 

public class Highlighting
{   
    public List<string> _text_ { get; set; }
}
```

Why does this work?  If I simplify the value of `"highlighting"` like so:

```
"highlighting": {
   "File Name 1":{ "_text_":[ "text 1" ] },
   "File name 2":{ "_text_":[ "text 2" ] }
}
```

We can see that it is a JSON object with variable property names that have a fixed schema for their values.  Json.NET supports serializing this to and from a dictionary; for details see [*Deserialize a Dictionary*](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDictionary.htm).

Sample fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dWCNLl).